# How to create a running total input field in django form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-forms, django-templates

How to create a running total using javascript in django form.

This is my model:

```
class Contra(models.Model):
    date       = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
    account    = models.ForeignKey(ledger1,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='contraledgers')

class Particularscontra(models.Model):
    contra     = models.ForeignKey(Contra,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='contras')
    particular = models.ForeignKey(ledger1,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='particularcontra')
    amount     = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,decimal_places=2,null=True)
```

This is my form:

```
class ContraForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Contra
        fields = ('date','account')
        widgets = {
            'date': DateInput(),
        }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ContraForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['account'].widget.attrs = {'class': 'form-control select2',}



class ParticularscontraForm(forms.ModelForm):

        class Meta:
            model = Particularscontra
            fields = ('particular','amount')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ParticularscontraForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['particular'].widget.attrs = {'class': 'form-control select2',}
        self.fields['amount'].widget.attrs = {'class': 'form-control',}

Contra_formSet = inlineformset_factory(Contra, Particularscontra,
                                            form=ParticularscontraForm, extra=6)
```

This 
I tried this previously but was unsuccessful:

```
{% block content %}

<div class="content-wrapper">


<!-- <div class="container"> -->
      <section class="content-header">
        <!-- <div class="col-md-12 col-md-offset-4"> -->
          <h1>
            <strong>Company : {{company_details.Name}}</strong>
          </h1>
                <ol class="breadcrumb">
                       <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Home</a></li>
                       <!-- <li><a href="#">Company list</a></li> -->
                     <li class="">Company list</li>
                     <li class="active">Create Simple Unit</li>
            </ol>
        <!-- </div> -->


      </section>

  <section class="content">

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
          <!-- Horizontal Form -->
          <div class="box">
            <div class="box-header with-border">
            {% if not form.instance.pk %}
              <h3 class="box-title"><strong>Create Contra</strong></h3>
            {% else %}
              <h3 class="box-title"><strong>Update Contra</strong></h3>
            {% endif %}
            </div>
            <!-- /.box-header -->
            <!-- form start -->
            <form method="POST" class="form-horizontal">

            {% csrf_token %}


        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="box box-success">

              <div class="box-body form-responsive no-padding">

                <br>
                 <br>
                <div class="col-md-2">  

                    <div class="form-group">
                       <label for="PAN1" class="col-md-4 control-label">Account<i class="material-icons" style="font-size:16px;color:red">*</i></label>
                       <div class="col-md-8">
                        {{ form.account }}
                      </div>
                    </div> 

                </div> 


                 <div class="col-md-10">

                    <div class="form-group">
                       <label for="State1" class="col-md-4 control-label">Date<i class="material-icons" style="font-size:16px;color:red">*</i></label>
                       <div class="col-md-8">
                        {{form.date}}
                      </div>
                    </div> 



                 </div>


              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="box box-success">

              <div class="box-body table-responsive no-padding">
                <table class="table">
                    {{ contras.management_form }}

                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th class="col-md-6">Particulars<i class="material-icons" style="font-size:16px;color:red">*</i></th>
                          <th class="col-md-6">Amount<i class="material-icons" style="font-size:16px;color:red">*</i></th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>

                        <tbody id="calculate">
                            {% for form in contras.forms %}

                                <tr class='{% cycle "row1" "row2" %}  formset_row'>
                                  <td class="col-md-6">{{ form.id }} {{ form.particular}}</td>
                                  <td class="col-md-6 amounts">{{ form.amount}}</td>
                                </tr>  

                            {% endfor %}




                        </tbody>


                        <tr>
                            <td class="col-md-6"></td>
                            <td class="col-md-6" id="totaled"><input type="text" name="total"></td>
                        </tr>
                </table>

              </div>


            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
              <!-- /.box-body -->
              <div class="box-footer">
               <button class="btn btn-default" type="reset" value="Reset">Reset</button>
                {% if not form.instance.pk %}
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info pull-right" value="Submit">Create</button>
                {% else %}
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info pull-right" value="Submit">Update</button>
                {% endif %}


             </div>
              <!-- /.box-footer -->
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>





    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'formset/jquery.formset.js' %}"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('.formset_row').formset({
            addText: 'add contra',
            deleteText: 'remove',
            prefix: 'contras'
        });
    </script>


    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
      let tableInstance = $('#calculate td.amounts');
      let totals = 0;
      tableInstance.each(function() {
        totals = totals + Math.floor($(this).text() * 100) / 100;
      });
      $(".totaled :input").val(totals);
    });

    </script>

    </section>
    </div>




    {% endblock %}
```

This is the javascript code I tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(e){  
  $('#calculate tbody').change(function(){
       var totals = 0;
       $(".amounts").each(function(){
            totals = totals + parseInt($(this).val());

        })
        $(".totaled").val(totals);
    });
 });
</script>
```

I am using inline formset in my template I want to display the running total of all the amount given in my inline form..

How is that possible to do it in django?

any guess?

Thank you

Comment: .amounts is not a form element so you cant have $(this).val() but you can use html() or innerhtml to get text inside td

Comment: nope its working at all

Comment: can you show rendered sample

Comment: You mean the screenshot of the template?or?

Comment: I have updated my question @Pavan Kumar T S

Comment: I meant html from browser final output html so that we can see Whats wrong.just go to developer console in browser and copy paste table html from source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if someone is still looking for an answer to this. This is the code I used. 'total' is the id of a span element, where the running total is shown.

```
$("input.numberinput").change(function(){
    sum=0
    $("input.numberinput").each(function(){
        sum += parseInt($(this).val());
        })
    $('#total').text(sum);
})
```

Comment: It would help if you extend/ build on the snippet code in the question. More likely that your answer will be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Select each td class `amounts`, iterate and add over them.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let tableInstance = $('#calculate td.amounts');
  let totals = 0;
  tableInstance.each(function() {
    totals = totals + Math.floor($(this).text() * 100) / 100;
  });
  $(".totaled :input").val(totals);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<table class="table" id="calculate">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="col-md-6">Particulars <i class="material-icons" style="font-size:16px;color:red">*</i></th>
      <th class="col-md-6">Amount <i class="material-icons" style="font-size:16px;color:red">*</i></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="row1  formset_row">
      <td class="col-md-6">1</td>
      <td class="col-md-6 amounts">5.2</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="row2  formset_row">
      <td class="col-md-6">2</td>
      <td class="col-md-6 amounts">5.5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="col-md-6"></td>
      <td class="col-md-6 totaled"><input type="text" name="total"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Nope I have tried exactly what you have done...But the output is NaN

Comment: By the way     `{{ form.amount}}` is a decimal field. Is this something to concern about?

Comment: Can you show clear rendered content rather than django tags?

Comment: You view on you own, how perfectly its been working now. Decimals are also supported. If there is till problem, there is problem in data source some where. You need to show rendered content here in order to debug correctly.

Comment: nope its not working in a formset...If you pul the value manually(like you have done) in a html...Then it is calculating the result

Comment: what form set you are talking about? Put your actual html page. There is problem in your JavaScript not the django. So please put your html whole rendered content  from <body> to </body>.

Comment: I will be pleased if you put html source code from browser. I need to see how your table data are being rendered so that I can debug. I just need you page source not the django template source.